# Creating plot for grouped factorial data

Tags: r, graph, plot

I have been looking a long time to solve what I think is a simple and basic problem: creating a suitable plot for my data.

My dataset consists of several variables (int and num --> columns) for several countries (factorial --> rows). In addition, this this is repeated for 3 years (groups --> also a column repeating itself for every country).

Creating boxplots for 1 variable is easy: `boxplot(log(variable)~year, data=df)`
(no layout is necessary here).

However, I would like to create 2 different plots:

- a graph similar to following plot but with lines that follow each point over the 3 years (like plotting the data of 1 country and connecting the points, but for all countries combined in 1 plot) I wish I could add a graph to make my request clearer.

  ```
  with(plot(log(variable)~year, type="p"), data=df
  ```
- A plot where the means of different variables are connected in different colours over the 3 years. So in a way similar to the previous graph but then instead of several countries and 1 variable, the mean of all the countries and several variables.

I hope this request is clear; since this is my first post I might have skipped some essential information. 
I wished I could add a picture but I can't do that yet.

(edit) My dataset basically looks like this:

```
structure(list(pooled.Country = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Angola", 
"Angola", "Angola", "Cameroon", "Cameroon", "Cameroon", 
"Chad"), class = "factor"), Forest = c(59728000L, 2675000L, 
12535000L, 6914000L, 22345000L, 22903000L), Pop = c(13138265L, 
6154708L, 1695587L, 11621159L, 14976200L, 3559604L), year = c(1998L, 
2002, 2006L, 1998L, 2002L, 2006L)), .Names = c("Country", 
"Forest", "Pop", "year"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

All help is very much welcomed (also on how to make potential future posts more clear).

Louis

Comment: Provide some data...use dput(your_data) and add the output to your question.

Comment: I think what you want is relatively straightforward (good news), but the precise code/method to produce this will depend on how your data is structured. As @MihaTrošt says, please provide some of your data then we can offer a specific solution. There are also some tips here about providing enough information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks!  I edited my question with an adapted version of my "head(data.set)"; hope this sheds a better light on my question